# Custom action names in API Blueprint

Tags: apiblueprint

I'm trying to write up an API and struggling to figure out a nice way of adding custom actions to a resource. For example, in my User resource I want to have the actions `enabled` and `disable`, but within the usual blueprint grouping I can't add these under a group:

```
## User [/users/{id}]

### Update a User [PATCH]
    ...

### Delete a User [DELETE]
    ...

### Disable a User [PATCH]
    ....
```

Here, the `Disable a User` and `Update a User` both point to the same URL which isn't what I want. I want these to produce the URLs `/users/{id}` and `/users/{id}/disable` respectively.

Looking through other API source, others have done it without using named resources, which would give:

```
## /users/{id}

    ### Update a User [PATCH]
        ...

    ### Delete a User [DELETE]
        ...

## /users/{id}/disable

    ### Disable a User [PATCH]
        ...
```

Whilst I can use this approach, I'd prefer to use the first approach as it's cleaner when it gets rendered by most blueprinting tools.

Is there a way of having custom actions using the first approach, or does anyone else have a cleaner way of implementing the same kind of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, because there are two different URLs, you actually will end up with two separate resources. One resource is a User resource, while the other is a Disable User resource. To organize these in your API Blueprint, you can group these resources together with a [Resource Group](https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/blob/master/API%20Blueprint%20Specification.md#def-resourcegroup-section).

```
# Group User Resources

## User [/users/{id}]

### Update a User [PATCH]
    ...

### Delete a User [DELETE]
    ...

## Disable User [/users/{id}/disable]

### Disable User [PATCH]
    ...
```

This allows you to have separate actions on separate URLs while keeping them tied together in your documentation.

Comment: Is there no way of having different URL's within the same resource though? I've already tried this approach (have it right now in fact) but I don't really want a disable and enable resource as separate things as I've got to then duplicate the model for each one when it's exactly the same

Comment: In API Blueprint, a resource is tied directly to a URL, so to have a different URL is to have a different resource. I think this means in your example you will essentially have two resources. If you would like to reuse your models, I believe you can do this. I threw up a Gist to show reusing a model for the user. https://gist.github.com/smizell/48a5f8d4ede6e86e3219

Comment: Looks to be about at close as I can get, at least that lets me re-use the model which is my main concern. Thanks :)